# Paypal - We're sorry, we could not send an IPN - Django

Tags: python, django, apache, paypal, mod-wsgi

I'm using Paypal with Django. Two months ago Paypal IPN was working fine, but now it fails. And Paypal IPN Simulator gives me this error:

```
We're sorry, we could not send an IPN.
```

I'm using django with Apache WSGI. Here you have my server configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin marcos@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/domain/domain.wsgi

    Alias /static/ /var/www/domain/static/
    Alias /media/ /var/www/domain/media/

    <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location>

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088697/paypal-ipns-not-sending-being-received-on-sandbox) they say that the problem is the usage of non-standard ports, but I'm using port "80".

The form that i'm using to send paypal is this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@domain.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Title">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="gD9s3nj4eW">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="26.90">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.com/thanks/">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://domain.com/canceled/">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://domain.com/paypal_response">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="confirmar-compra">Confirmar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could it be that your paypal merchant account has expired or has been disabled?

Comment: No, It's not expired

Comment: This sounds mundane, but log into your account on paypal, and double check that the value for the "business" is the same as what is on file. Make sure it wasn't changed or typo'd.

Comment: It's not the problem :(

Comment: can you check the apache logs to see which HTTP Status Code is being returned, plz? Sounds more like a script issue, rather than Server Config.

If this is the case, have a gander at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882891/paypal-ipn-not-calling-issue/23891760#23891760